# Extract WordPress post attachments to unordered list outside of post

Tags: jquery, wordpress, post, html-lists

I am trying to:

1. Search a WP post for attachments (img and iframes)
2. Move these outside of the post to a location earlier in the code hierarchy
3. Present each one as a list-item in an unordered list, so that they are available to various slider/gallery plugins.

The problem is, I can't see how to cycle through the items to assign `<li>` tags while also dynamically adding a wrapper `<ul>` if one is called for.

Currently, I have this code, but am not experienced enough with jQuery to know what I'm doing wrong:

```
jQuery("document").ready (function(){

   jQuery(".para img, .para iframe").(function(){
    var nUl = jQuery("<ul></ul>");
    nUl.prependTo(jQuery(this).parents(".content-inset-wrap"));
 })
 jQuery(this).each(function(){
  var nLi = jQuery("<li></li>");
  nLi.appendTo(nUl);
  nLi.append(this);

})
```

});

I am aware that there may be an alternate way of doing this, using a direct WP query for post attachments, but have absolutely no idea how this works; and I don't see any reason why not to attempt it in straight up js as above. And I suspect the `<ul>` and `<li>` looping issue would remain in any case.

For what it's worth, this code does what I'm trying to do but presents the looping issue, as each image or iframe found gets its own `<ul>` as well as `<li>`:

```
jQuery("document").ready (function(){
jQuery(".para img, .para iframe").each(function(){

  var nUl = jQuery("<ul></ul>");
  var nLi = jQuery("<li></li>");

  nUl.prependTo(jQuery(this).parents(".content-inset-wrap"));
  nLi.appendTo(nUl);

  nLi.append(this);

})
```

});

Any help very much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: "Move these outside of the post to a location earlier in the code hierarchy" what do you mean?

Comment: @David They currently appear in the post wrapper, i.e. in .content-inset-wrap > .para > img.
I'd like to move them up the hierarchy, so that visually they appear before things like the post title, date, etc. i.e. prepend them. Hope this is clearer?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("document").ready (function(){

jQuery('.para').each(function() {
var html='';
 html='<ul>';

jQuery('img', this).each(function() {
    html+= '<li>'+ jQuery(this).prop('outerHTML') +'</li>';
    console.log(html);
    jQuery(this).remove();
});

jQuery('iframe', this).each(function() {
  html+= '<li>'+jQuery(this).prop('outerHTML')+'</li>';
  jQuery(this).remove();
});

html += '</ul>';

jQuery(this).parent('.content-inset-wrap').prepend(html);
});


});
```

Comment: That almost works. The .para class has both text and images (and iframes) in it, so I need to extract the images and iframes while leaving the text. Currently, implementing your code and adding `img` after the `.para` selector simply removes the images entirely and adds the right number of `<li>` tags (but without images) just inside the content-inset-wrap.

I'm also unfamiliar with what you seem to be doing here - it looks like you're redefining the variables on the fly?

Comment: basically each will cycle through each element so you are building a variable to insert higher up. have you got a link to where you are doing this?

Comment: No link - developing locally - but I could upload if this would help?

Comment: I've created a fiddle to show the problem, using your code and the relevant part of my site. http://jsfiddle.net/conrad89/4u3Wx/

Comment: ok you owe me big time for this. i updated a new version above Your problem is there is no identifiers and .next() dosent seem to work....see working here. http://jsfiddle.net/dheffernan/58eQ6/

Comment: Many thanks for all your work on this, but it's still not quite doing what I'm aiming for. I want to leave the text where it is, and only extract the images and iframes. In your latest fiddle the text is moving with the images and iframes, which defeats the purpose of preparing a clean `<ul>` for use by an image gallery plugin.

Comment: That is almost perfect! One final thing: instead of adding all the images and iframes found to one new div that is hard coded into the theme at a certain location, I need something like `jQuery(this).parents(".content-inset-wrap").append(html);` at the end so that the new `<ul>` is dynamically added before each post. At the moment your code is pull all images and iframes from all posts and moving them to one place in `#newdiv`.

Comment: thats a little bit different again. You need to cycle through each .para and within the each get the elements.

Comment: Could I not just use something like a `.closest` rather than `.parents`? This doesn't work.. but something like this should?

Comment: used parent instead of parents working in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/dheffernan/44HTP/2/